# Show hide html attribute based on model var in Razor - "@" must be followed by a valid code block

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am using razor to show/hide page content based on variables in the model:

```
     @if (Model.TicketShown == null)
        {
            @:<div id="ticket-section">
        } else {
            @:<div id="ticket-section" style="display:none">
        }

       //More Code

     @:</div>
```

I have been using it for a while, but today I am getting the error '"@" must be followed by a valid code block' just on the closing tag. I am using the syntax elsewhere and it works fine.

Why and is there a more elegant way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@:` is meant to be used inside code blocks (see [Explicit line transition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#razor-code-blocks)), your `@:</div>` might not be inside one. You could use [Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#expression-encoding) as alternative (e.g. `@Html.Raw("</div>")`).

With the help of the [?: operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), you could also rewrite the if as follows:

```
<div id="ticket-section" style=@(Model.TicketShown == null ? "" : "display:none")>
    ...
</div>
```